# Bounded interval such that finite sub collections are nonempty, but entire intersections are empty

Tags: real-analysis

So I am working out of Rudin and am trying to prove that for a collection $\{K_{n}\}$ of bounded subsets of a metric space where the $K_{i}\bigcap K_j$ for every finite sub collection of $\{K_n\}$ is not empty.  But the $\bigcap K$ for the entire set is empty.

So the bounded interval I chose was the collection of sets as $K_{n}$={$(0,\frac{1}{n}) | n \in \mathbb{N}$}

Note for any finite intersection of this family, the intersection is not null.

But if I intersection the entire family for $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} K_{i}$ = $\emptyset$

is this correct?  Did I state the problem correctly?  please let me know if I said anything unclear.

Comment: Yep, that works.

Comment: I don't have my copy here, but the statement cannot be correct. Maybe you are trying to **find** a collection $\{K_n\}$ with the given properties. If so, you have found one.

Comment: It says "IF $\{K_n\}$ is a collection of bounded sets of a metric space X, show that the intersection of every finite sub collection is not null, but then all intersections is null.  I think my family collection is okay?

Comment: yes, I am trying to show that this statement is only for compact sets, not bounded or closed sets, so the lemma for bounded / closed sets does not apply as it does for compact.